# Does SWFJunkie Tweetr's PHP Proxy still work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, twitter, proxy, twitter-oauth

I've recently been asked to help support a system which uses the PHP Proxy provided by SWFJunkie.  In following the proxy's install steps I get to Step 4 at which point I get no results.  I've tried hosting on Apache and IIS, have confirmed that URL rewrites work correctly on both platforms and that CURL is correctly installed, and have ensured there are no firewalls blocking my requests.

In researching this issue I've seen that Twitter have been changing their API rules (with more changes set to take place in March next year).  The last activity I can see on the Proxy project was back in 2010, after which it seems to have gone dead.  Before I put in more effort trying to get this to work I thought I'd ask - is anyone else currently using this / do you have it working?

If you have it working I'd welcome any tips / advice you have also, but mainly I just want to know in advance whether this utility still works in order to justify spending time on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proxy does still work, but I had to tweak the code a little.

Thanks to @MikeHayes for the solution: [Twitter OAUTH - returns response code of "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055157/twitter-oauth-returns-response-code-of-0)

For anyone else having this issue, the quick fix is to update Tweetr.php.  Find the code matching what's below & insert the additional (commented) line on the end.

```
$opt[CURLOPT_URL] = $twitterURL;
$opt[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->userAgent;
$opt[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$opt[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 60;
//BEGIN UPDATED CODE
$opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
//END UPDATED CODE
```

Thanks again to Mike & good luck to anyone else currently having this issue.